# Vertical scrollbar destroys design

Tags: css

I created a responsive design for my website that contains two fixed containers - header and footer. Yesterday I discovered that fixed containers make problems in some mobile phones when I convert my website into an app (using webview).

So, I found another solution that uses display:table, display:table-row and display:table-cell.

Everything works fine:

[image]

but if I paste a long text, appears vertical scrollbar and desproys the desing.

[image]

Blue and yellow containers must stay un the same position (I can not set fixed width because design must be responsive). I don't want to hide the scrollbar if it's needed.

How do I fix this problem?

**HTML**

```
<div class="mn_tab">
  <div class="mn_row_head">
    <div class="mn_cell_inner">    
      <div class="mn_head_in">    
        Header
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mn_content">
    <div class="mn_cell_inner">
      <div class="mn_txt">    
        <div class="mn_hre">            
          <p>Content</p>
          <p>Content</p>
          <p>Content</p>
          <p>Content</p>
          <p>Content</p>
          <p>Content</p>
          <p>Content</p>
          <p>Content</p>
          <p>Content</p>
          <p>Content</p>
          <p>Content</p>
          <p>Content</p>
          <p>Content</p>
          <p>Content</p>
          <p>Content</p>
          <p>Content</p>
          <p>Content</p>
          <p>Content</p>
          <p>Content</p>
          <p>Content</p>
          <p>Content</p>
          <p>Content</p>
          <p>Content</p>
          <p>Content</p>
          <p>Content</p>
          <p>Content</p>             
          <p>Content</p>
          <p>Content</p>
          <p>Content</p>
          <p>Content</p>
          <p>Content</p>
          <p>Content</p>
          <p>Content</p>
          <p>Content</p>
          <p>Content</p>
          <p>Content</p>
          <p>Content</p>
          <p>Content</p>
          <p>Content</p>             
          <p>Content</p>
          <p>Content</p>
          <p>Content</p>
          <p>Content</p>
          <p>Content</p>
          <p>Content</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mn_row_foot">
    <div class="mn_cell_inner">Footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.mn_tab {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}

.mn_row_head,
.mn_content,
.mn_row_foot {
  display: table-row;
}

.mn_row_head,
.mn_row_foot {
  background: silver;
}

.mn_cell_inner {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
}

.mn_content .mn_cell_inner {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: pink;
}

.mn_txt {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.mn_head_in {
  background: blue;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

.mn_hre {
background: yellow;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the next code to remove the scroll bar

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

Hope this helps :>

```css
    html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.mn_tab {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}

.mn_row_head,
.mn_content,
.mn_row_foot {
  display: table-row;
}

.mn_row_head,
.mn_row_foot {
  background: silver;
}

.mn_cell_inner {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
}

.mn_content .mn_cell_inner {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: pink;
}
.mn_txt {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.mn_head_in {
  background: blue;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

.mn_hre {
background: yellow;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  }
  
  
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="mn_tab">
  <div class="mn_row_head">
    <div class="mn_cell_inner">

      <div class="mn_head_in">

        Header

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mn_content">
    <div class="mn_cell_inner">
      <div class="mn_txt">

        <div class="mn_hre">



<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>

         <p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>

         <p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>

         <p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>

         <p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>



        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mn_row_foot">
    <div class="mn_cell_inner">Footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To limit the code that "removes" the scrollbar you can add a media query:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... I need another solution because it should work in all devices. A website without vertical scrollbar in a desktop or laptop will look strange

Comment: @Verode, Then you can add a media query to that style. Actually y like sites without scroll bars. I like how a site cover 100% of the width.

Comment: media query to do what? I agree, websites without scroll bars maybe lok better but I like to know how large is page and where I am.